# MySQL query group by with multiple sum values

Tags: mysql

If you review this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85415/1), you will see that the resulting data is grouped by Year and Type which means that there are 2 rows for each year.  I would like to only group on the year, and display the Sum of the A-type and the B-type on the same row.

Can someone please tell me how I would modify the sum statements in this query so that the first sum is only for the A-type, and the second sum is for the B-type?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the two columns, it's fairly easy to do;

```
SELECT Year, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Type='A' THEN Amt ELSE 0 END) TypeA,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Type='B' THEN Amt ELSE 0 END) TypeB
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Year
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85415/8).

...or a bit more verbose standard SQL;

Comment: Thanks very much.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I don't really understand the syntax, though.  What does this mean:  Amt*(Type='A')    ???  What does the * do?

Comment: @DanielAttard Changed to more readable standard SQL, the former was MySQL specific and harder to read.

Comment: Awesome.  I understand the verbose version.  Thanks again.  Made my night!

Answer (score 1):

How about this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85415/11

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF(TYPE = 'A', Amt, 0)) AS A_amt,
  SUM(IF(TYPE = 'B', Amt, 0)) AS B_amt,
  YEAR,
  TYPE
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY YEAR
```

Alternatively you could use a `CASE` statement which is standard SQL, but slightly longer so I opted for this version.

Comment: Thanks Wolph.  I learned a bunch from your post.  Appreciate it.